# Under what circumstances is a m-class classification Neural Network equal to a base category logit model for nominal responses

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, logistic, categorical-data

Here is the setup for an m-class classification neural network.

$$z_j=\sigma(\alpha_0j+\alpha_j^T x), (j=1,...,k)$$
$$t=\beta_0+\Sigma^k_{j=1}\beta_j z_j)=\beta_0+\beta^Tx, (l=1,...,m)$$
$$ y=f(x)=g(t),  (l=1,...,m)$$

And here is the baseline category logit model for nominal responses:

$$log (\pi_j(x)/ \pi_k(x))=x^T\beta, (j=1,...,k-1)$$

(some of the above are matrices but i can't bold them - i don't know how so any tips on that would be appreciated)

I have a question that asks how the NN can be made equivalent? ie under what constraint and what discrepancy function. My thoughts are:

- remove the hidden layer
- set the discrepancy function to the negative of the log likelihood of the Bernoulli distribution (because this is needed in classification tasks)
- set the $\sigma(.)$ function to something that'll then sort everything out (but I don't know what).

Any ideas gang?